# Hopf fibration from $SO(3)$ Lie algebra generators?

Tags: lie-algebras, quaternions, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry, hopf-fibration

One can use the Pauli matrices $\sigma_i$ to generate $Cl_3(\mathbb{R})$ and taking commutators of these matrices gives the $SU(2)$ Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)=\biggl(\begin{matrix}
ia&-z\\
z&-ia\\
\end{matrix}\biggr)$

However, one can also generate $Cl_3(\mathbb{R})$ using the $4\times4$ quaternion Cayley Matrices:$R_i=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}, R_j =\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}, R_k = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

These matrices act on 4-collumn unit spinors which from what I understand are elements of Spin(3), yet the associated Lie algebra of Spin(3) is generated by the following $3\times3$ matrices:

$\pi_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&-1\\
0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}, \pi_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
-1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}, \pi_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

I'm stuck on how one derives these matrices from the $Cl_3(\mathbb{R})$ generators.

Moreover, in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02569.pdf The author writes on page 8 that the Hopf fibration is given by the map: $\Psi \pi_i \Psi^T$ where $\Psi \in\mathbb{H}$ but how can a $3\times 3$ matrix act on a quaternion, which is a 4-column, or can be represented by a $2\times2$ or $4\times4$ matrix? This makes perfect sense to me if one replaces $\pi_i$ with $\sigma_i$ then the Hopf fibration arises if we turn the quaternions into $2\times 2$ matrices but I have no idea how $\pi_i$ act on quaternions.

Comment: Note: On the Lie algebra level, $\mathfrak{su}_2 \simeq \mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb R)$, and since the complexification of this is $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, there is up to equivalence exactly one irreducible representation of this via $n \times n$-matrices for *any* $n$. In general it is not given that you can easily convert those into one another. In the low dimensions at hand though, it might help that that Lie algebra is also the (3-dimensional) space of *pure* quaternions with commutator bracket, which exponentiates to the (3-dimensional) Lie group of *unit* quaternions, cf. the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The $3\times 3$ Lie algebra matrices, you have quoted, would act on the quaternion expressed as a $3\times 3$ matrix, i.e. the SO(3) group.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Rather than on a quaternion represented as a 4-column, a $2\times2$ complex matrix [SU(2)], or a $4\times4$ real matrix, as is my understanding.

A quaternion $q=a+bi+cj+dk$ is written in SO(3):
\begin{equation}
\Psi\;=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2 & 2(bc-ad) & 2(bd+ac) \\
2(bc+ad) & a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2 & 2(cd-ab) \\
2(bd-ac) & 2(cd+ab) & a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The Lie algebra matrices can be used in matrix exponentiation, for example to define a $3\times 3$ quaternion (a rotation matrix) using the roll-pitch-yaw angles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

\begin{align}
\exp(\theta \pi_1)\;&=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
0 & \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}\\
\exp(\theta \pi_2)\;&=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & \sin(\theta) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}\\
\exp(\theta \pi_3)\;&=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).